Double summation limit with denominator term
Is there any general theory talking about if the following limit
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1/n \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n f(x_i,x_j)}{\sum_{j=1}^n g(x_i,x_j)}
$$
converges to
$$
\int\frac{\int f(x,y) d\mu(x)}{\int g(x,y) d\mu(x)} d\mu(y)?
$$
Here $ \forall i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ we have i.i.d. samples $x_i \sim \mu$.
Due to the summation in denominator, I don't think I can apply the standard U statistics.
Can I split the summation into double summation with respect to different index, i.e. n and m?
Any hint would be very helpful! Many thanks in advance.

I don't have a result to supply. My intuition is that I'm worried about some cross-terms appearing and making the result slightly different than your formula. To study this, assume that everything is simple: both $f$ and $g$ are bounded, with bounded derivatives etc and the $x_i$ are bounded too. then see if you can express compound terms as a mean + error and perform rough delta approximations. I would also run some simulation studies with asymetric $x$ and irregular $g,f$ to check this conjecture and any future ones. Bon courage.

Thanks for the suggestion. Running some simulation is a good idea.
